# Java File Input Output Stream Race Condition

Tags: java, inputstream, race-condition, outputstream

I'm having trouble getting my results. I'm supposed to get

```
0 1 2 3 .....3000
```

After running the code, but I get this:

```
65488
65489
65489 
5528
65529
65529
65529
65530
65531
65531
65531
65532
65532
65532
65533
6553......
```

For my assignment I need to build a (sum) code with the following conditions:

1. It reads the last data of the file and adds a 1 to the data
2. 0 must be the first data of the file
   ex) 0 1 2 .....
3. It runs the program 1000 times (0 to 1000 so total 1001 records)

The data file's "open" and "close" must be ran in the "Load" and "Store" functions respectively.

Someone help me please :(

**Class Race_Condition**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Race_Condition {
    static int x=0;

    public int Load(int x) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/out");
        int count;
        byte[] b = new byte[1024]; 
        while ((count = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
                x= (char) b[i]; 
            }
        }
        fis.close();
        return x;
    }

    public void Store(int data) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src/out");
        fos.write(x);
        fos.close();
        System.out.println(x);
    }   

    public  int Add(int i,int j) {
        return i+j ;
    }

    public void sum() throws Exception  {
        for (int i=0 ; i<1000 ; i++) { 

            Race_Condition.x=Load(x);
            Race_Condition.x=Add(x,1);
            Store(x);       
        }       
    }
}
```

**class Race_Condtion2**

```
   import java.io.*;
 public class Race_Condition2 extends Thread{

 Race_Condition R= new Race_Condition();

  public void run() {
    try {
    R.sum();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }  
}
```

**Main class**

```
import java.io.*;
public class Race_ConditonTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {

        Race_Condition2 R1 = new Race_Condition2();
        Race_Condition2 R2 = new Race_Condition2();
        Race_Condition2 R3 = new Race_Condition2();


        R1.start();
        R2.start();
        R3.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use multiple threads? is it required ?

Comment: You have no thread synchronization. [Java - Thread Synchronization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm)

Comment: Also, you are reading bytes, but you want to read/write ints. You probably want to read/write the int values as strings with a space separator.

Comment: When you write the values, you don't move to the end of the file. See [`FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String,%20boolean))